# NaN value is auto-input when pressing tab or onclick fucntion present

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Hello devs/programmers/coders.. When I press Tab to proceed to the next row NaN value is automatically inputted, and even onclick gives me NaN, then the sum of the total column will NaN and will not change.. I have no idea on how will I remove the NaN value... please help me! Here is my code:

```
<html>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "styling.css?version=3"></link>
    <body>

    <div id='acctdetails' style='padding-left: 15% '>
            <?php
            echo "USERNAME: ". $_SESSION["dynau"]; 
            ?>

                OR Date: <input type='text' placeholder='OR Date' name='ordate' value='<?php echo date('M, d, Y');?>'>

                OR ID: <input type='text' placeholder='OR ID' name='orid'>

                Payor : <input type='text' placeholder='Payor' name='payor' >
    </div>


    <center>
        <form method="POST">
            <?php       
    $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM account_db");

    echo"<html>";
    echo "<script>";
    echo "function calculate(amount, id){ 
          document.getElementById('total' + id).innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('copy' + id).value) * amount; 
             var x=parseInt(document.getElementById('total' + id).innerHTML);
                var y = document.getElementById('sumtotal').innerHTML;
                var a = y.split(' ');
                var z = parseInt(a[1]) + parseInt(x);
                document.getElementById('sumtotal').innerHTML = 'Total: ' + z;

            }";
    echo "</script>";
    echo"<center>";
    echo "<form method='POST'>";
    echo "<br></br>";
    echo "<table style='border:1px solid black' id='thetable' name='pleasework'>";
    echo"<th>FILES</th>";
    echo"<th>AMOUNT</th>";
    echo"<th>NO. OF COPIES</th>";
    echo"<th>TOTAL AMOUNT</th>";

    $counter = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo "<td >$row[1] </td>";
        echo "<td align=center>$row[2] </td>";
        echo "<td align=center>
                <input type='number' id='copy" . $counter . "' onkeyup='calculate(" . $row[2] .  ", " . $counter . ")'> 
                </td>";
            echo "<td align=center id='total" . $counter . "'></td>";
        echo"</tr>";
        $counter++;
        }   


    echo"<tr>
            <td  id='sumtotal'>TOTAL: 0</td>
        </tr>";


    echo "</table>";
    echo " <br><div style='padding-left: 15px'><input type='submit' id='btn1' value='Transact' name='transaction' onclick='javascript: window.print()'></div>";
    echo"</center>";
    echo"</html>";      
?>      
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is in this line:

```
document.getElementById('total' + id).innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('copy' + id).value) * amount;
```

In order to understand the issue you can try by yourself:

```
parseInt('')
```

The result of the previous operation is **[undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)**, so:

```
parseInt('')+amount
```

will be **[NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)** (not a number).

That means you need to test the value before to proceed with the computation:

```
!!ele.value.trim()   --> value is not empty
```

I suggest you to use:

> [.value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) (for input field): The initial value of the control. This attribute is optional except when the value of the type attribute is radio or checkbox.
>   Note that when reloading the page, Gecko and IE will ignore the value specified in the HTML source, if the value was changed before the reload.
>
> .[textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)(for cell with text values): represents the text content of a node and its descendants

instead of:

> [.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) : sets or gets the HTML syntax describing the element's descendants.

Moreover, in order to simplify your code you may consider to traverse the dom in order to get the values contained in the other two sibling cells.

Use the keyword **this** in your case. This keyword stands for the current element, so you don't need to get it from the dom.

The snippet:

```js
function calculate(ele) {
  if (!!ele.value.trim()) {
      var x = +ele.value * +ele.parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent.trim();
      var y = +document.getElementById('sumtotal').textContent.trim().split(' ').pop();
      ele.parentElement.nextElementSibling = x;
      var z = x + y;
      document.getElementById('sumtotal').textContent = 'Total: ' + z;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='acctdetails' style='padding-left: 15% '>
    USERNAME: ...
    OR Date: <input type='text' placeholder='OR Date' name='ordate' value='01/01/2017'>
    OR ID: <input type='text' placeholder='OR ID' name='orid'>
    Payor : <input type='text' placeholder='Payor' name='payor'>
</div>
<form method="POST"><br/>
    <table style='border:1px solid black' id='thetable' name='pleasework'>
        <th>FILES</th>
        <th>AMOUNT</th>
        <th>NO. OF COPIES</th>
        <th>TOTAL AMOUNT</th>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td align=center>11</td>
            <td align=center>
                <input type='number' id='copy1' onkeyup="calculate(this)">
            </td>
            <td align=center id='total1'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id='sumtotal'>TOTAL: 0</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>

    <div style='padding-left: 15px'><input type='submit' id='btn1' value='Transact' name='transaction'
                                           onclick='javascript: window.print()'></div>
</form>
```